# How do I change the Old Directory path to New Directory path using SED command

Tags: sed

I have the old path it contains the some files.

```
 /home/ubuntu/Desktop/test-dir
```

Now I want to change the test-dir to new-test-dir directory.

```
 /home/ubuntu/Desktop/new-test-dir
```

How do I change this

Comment: mv /home/ubuntu/Desktop/test-dir  /home/ubuntu/Desktop/new-test-dir

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
mv /home/ubuntu/Desktop/{test-dir,new-test-dir}
```

Comment: I think he wants this for sed?

Comment: I asked using SED Command

Comment: You want to use `sed` to rename directory?

Comment: yes... i want to change directory name using sed command

Comment: @rajcoumar: So why do you want that? Do you know that `sed` is not used for renaming directory?